# I am getting following error when i try to show category products on homepage [Magento 1.8]

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am getting following error when i try to show featured products on homepage

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in
>   /home/superhit/public_html/eoffixplanet.com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 816

can anybody help?

Here is my [website](http://eoffixplanet.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to filter collection by non-existing attribute. Review your `->addAttributeToFilter('...')` calls.